# Split string into multiple strings

Tags: python

my knowledge is very limited, but I'm trying my best.

I want to split a string in multiple strings, variables.

Right now, I used a http server script, THANKS to: https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/2219997

Which I have modified just a little, I receive a POST string decode, and I want to split that string into different strings or variables.

This is the full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Very simple HTTP server in python.
Usage::
    ./dummy-web-server.py [<port>]
Send a GET request::
    curl http://localhost
Send a HEAD request::
    curl -I http://localhost
Send a POST request::
    curl -d "foo=bar&bin=baz" http://localhost
"""
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import SocketServer
import sys
import time
import csv
import urllib
import psycopg2


con = None

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write("<html><body><h1>hi!</h1></body></html>")

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
    # Doesn't do anything with posted data
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the size of data
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) # <--- Gets the data itself
        print post_data # <-- Print post data
        self._set_headers()
        dataEncoded = str(post_data)
        dataString = urllib.unquote(post_data)
        timeString = str(time.strftime("%d %m %Y %H:%M:%S"))
        with open("decoded_log.csv",'a') as resultFile:
            wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
            wr.writerow([dataString,timeString])
        with open("encoded_log.csv",'a') as resultFile:
            wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
            wr.writerow([dataEncoded,timeString])    
        con = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=data_log user=USER password=PASSWORD")
        print "DB Connection successful."
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO log(data,date_time) VALUES (%s, %s)",(dataString,timeString))
        con.commit()           

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=5400):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print 'Starting httpd...'
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv

    if len(argv) == 2:
        run(port=int(argv[1]))
    else:
        run()

sys.exit()
```

http://pastebin.com/nkbkD2iZ

Then i receive this string:

> %22%22%22%5B001%5D%22%22%3A%22%22C3643%22%22%2C%22%22%7C%5B002%5D%22%22%3A%22%2232303138%22%22%2C%22%22%7C%22%22%3D%22=

Which decoded is:

> """"C3643""""32303138"",""|""="=

So, what I want, and I have failed to do so, is to, extract C3643 and 32303138, then I will like to split 32303138 in:

> 32 303 138

So once is all done I want to have this strings:

> a = C3643 b = 32 c = 303 d = 138

So, then I can INSERT into the PostgreSQL columns, each value.

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the words with regex and then slice the string like so:

```
import re

s1 = """\"\"\"\"C3643\"\"\"\"32303138\"\",\"\"|\"\"=\"="""
print s1

s2 = re.findall(r'\w+', s1)
print s2

a = s2[0]
s3 = s2[1]

b,c,d = s3[:2], s3[2:5], s3[5:]
print a
print b
print c
print d
```

Output:

```
""""C3643""""32303138"",""|""="=
['C3643', '32303138']
C3643
32
303
138
```

Comment: Many thanks MYGz ! One thing I didnt mention, is that the string.

s1 = """
""""C3643""""32303138"",""|""="=
"""


The first Number C3643 ins this case, has variable length, but will be always in the first """"""inside""""", and the second number in this case 32303138, this will have the same length. So first number I will take it completily, and the next number I will split it in more numbers.

Comment: Those `"` have to be escaped, my bad. It luckily had even numbers of `"` so it concatenated together.

Comment: Give me 1 sec. I'll rectify it

Comment: @Bannedillo Check now.

Comment: @Bannedillo If it solved your problem, please consider [Accepting the Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/345277).

Answer (score 0):

For those of us you find regex incomprehensible:

```
>>> post="%22%22%22%5B001%5D%22%22%3A%22%22C3643%22%22%2C%22%22%7C%5B002%5D%22%22%3A%22%2232303138%22%22%2C%22%22%7C%22%22%3D%22="
>>> result= urllib.unquote(post).replace('"',"").split(',')
>>> a = result[0].split(':')[1]
>>> b = result[1].split(':')[1][:2]
>>> c = result[1].split(':')[1][2:5]
>>> d = result[1].split(':')[1][5:]
>>> a,b,c,d
('C3643', '32', '303', '138')
>>> a
'C3643'
>>> b
'32'
>>> c
'303'
>>> d
'138'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's giving me this error, 

model = dataString[1].split(':')[1][:2]
IndexError: list index out of range


For example with this post: %22%2200%3A0a9%3A59d6816%22%22%22%2232303138%22%22

Comment: Probably because that string decodes as `""00:0a9:59d6816""""32303138""` and does not follow the format that you originally posted. Try adding a test `if len(result) < 2: print "data error"`